# What is scanner.l and how is it different from lex.yy.c?

Tags: lex

I have read a few books and sites but I am still not clear about a lexer, scanner.l and the difference between a lexer and lex.yy.c, scanner and lexer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lex (or flex) take a scanner description, usually in a file whose extension is `.l`, and produce a C program which implements the scanner, often named `lex.yy.c` although you can (and should) use a more meaningful name. Many people use the word "lexer" to mean the same as "scanner"; you can consider them synonyms.